# Setting The Coordinates to the Center of The SVG Image

Tags: html, svg

Normally, the coordinates (0,0) is at the left top corner of the image but I want it to be in the center of the image, the image is 128 pixel 128 pixel so it should be at 64 pixel to 64 pixel. I do not know how to do this, can you guys help me?

The code below is created with Aseprite, and i exported it as an svg file. Also, this is not the full code, the rectangles x and y value goes to 128 pixels.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg version="1.1" width="128" height="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="1" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="2" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="3" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="4" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="5" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="6" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="7" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="8" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="9" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="10" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="11" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="12" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="13" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="14" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="15" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="16" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="17" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="18" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="19" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="20" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="21" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="22" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
<rect x="23" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#C2F8FF" />
```

Comment: try using a viewBox attribute like viewBox="-64 -64 128 128"

Comment: i tried that but it doesnt work, it corrupts the image and the 0,0 is still at the top left corner.

Comment: So you place ``<g>`` around all your rects, and translate it -64 -64 .. its math

Comment: actually i do not know much about svg and do not know how to use <g> tag, so i have little bit problem with that, sorry.

Comment: Then you read the fine manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g

Comment: Use `viewBox` like this: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="128" height="128" viewBox="-64 -64 128 128">`.

Comment: Please don't edit the title to say solved. If the answer helped you you can click on the tick mark to accept it if you want. If not, write your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comments suggest you can "move around" `0,0` by using the [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox). The first two numbers are the coordinate for the top left corner and that last to numbers are the width and the height. They are stating how the inner coordinate system is set up – not an expressing on the "actual" width and height (in this first example the width is 300 even though the viewBox is 128 in width) – these can be set with the width and height attributes.

```html
<svg viewBox="-64 -64 128 128" width="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="-64" y="-64" width="128" height="128" fill="steelblue"/>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60" fill="mediumpurple"/>
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="orange"/>
</svg>
```

An alternative is to use a [`<g>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) element for moving the `0,0` for all the child elements:

```html
<svg width="128" height="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="translate(64 64)">
    <rect x="-64" y="-64" width="128" height="128" fill="steelblue"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60" fill="mediumpurple"/>
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="orange"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```